# Remove all characters between 2 Regex patterns

Tags: powershell

I have a file full of lines like this :

```
04:50:03 [SomeText]        04:54:05
04:54:33 [Some other text] 04:54:56
04:56:43 [Another text]    04:57:09
...
```

I want to remove all the text between the two times (keeping only a semicolon) and output the desired result to another file that would look like this :

```
04:50:03;04:54:05
04:54:33;04:54:56
04:56:43;04:57:09
...
```

This is the regex pattern I'm using to match the dates : `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`

How can I achieve this using Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your timestamps are at the start and end of each line, use `^` and `$` to anchor them, then enclose them in a capture group and remove everything else:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*?(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)$','$1;$2'
```